# How can I set a standard layout for every device in android studio

Tags: java, android, layout

I was making an app and when I imported it to my phone I noticed that all the images and text had been sent to different places. Same with my tablet. Is there a way to keep that I can keep everything in the layout the same regardless of the screen size?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please upload your design screen sort.

Comment: Can you post your problematic XML code?

Answer (score 1):

why you don't try to use the constraint layout , its the best choice , and for picture use SVG , to avoid resize problems ,

check : https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

and for SVG : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

and also this tools helps you to convert the svg to vector drawable : http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is. You were working on DPs and i think it was a low one selected from right of the design window. But there is a "weight" attribute. You can make perfect fitting apps by using it.

"weight" basically using for dividing layouts on equal sizes. It makes fit all devices better then before because dp can be change but percent cannot. You can find more info about weight in here..

[Using layout_weight](https://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-layout-weight-attribute.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout and never give height in dp's (density pixels) because every phone and tablets have different resolutions and according to dp you have given they take place on screen. If you are using LinerLayout always use match_parent or wrap_content and if you want some elements in same row (horizontally) use layout-weight property .
Using match_parent , wrap_content , layout-weight these will set the elements  properly on the screen irrespective of phone,tablet etc..

hope it will solve your problem !